# Pygame colliderect is not working properly

Tags: python, class, pygame

I'm writing this code to build a simple square which moves left and right and can jump on a stage using the colliderect function in pygame but the problem is when the player(square) jumps on the stage its y coordinate changes to the y coordinate of the stage permanently and never falls down. Another big issue is that when the player is below the stage it should not be able to jump over the top but it does. My code contains four pages, first contains the main loop, second contains the player class, third contains stage class and forth part contains the basic game functions

Main--Pg 01

```
import pygame
from player import Player
import game_functions as gf
import sys
from stage import Stage
from pygame.sprite import Group

def run_game():
    # Intialise the game and start the screen
    pygame.init()   
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
    pygame.display.set_caption("AmarCreep")
    
    player = Player(screen)
    stage = Stage(screen)
    
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    
    # Main loop
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)
        
        # Navy screen
        screen.fill((173,216,249))
        
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # Check if user wants to quit
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()
            gf.responses(screen, player, event)
            
        # Update player's x-y coordinate
        player.p_movements(stage)
        
        stage.draw_stage()
        
        # Make the player appear
        player.draw_player()
        
        
        # Make the newly made screen visible
        pygame.display.flip()
    
run_game()
```

Player--Pg 02

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite


class Player(Sprite):
    # Initialise the main player
    
    def __init__(self, screen):
        super(Player, self).__init__()
        
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        
        # Specifying the position of the player at start 
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 30, 30)
        self.rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom = 590
        
        self.moving_left = False
        self.moving_right = False
        self.moving_up = False
        self.vel_y = 18
        
    def p_movements(self, stage):
        
        dx = 0
        dy = 0
        
        # Predict the player movements beforehand
        if self.moving_left and self.rect.x > 10:
            dx -= 7
        if self.moving_right and self.rect.x < 760:
            dx += 7 
        if self.moving_up:
            dy -= self.vel_y
            self.vel_y -= 2
            if self.vel_y < -18:
                self.moving_up = False
                self.vel_y = 18
                
            
            
        # Check collisions in x direction
        if stage.s_rect.colliderect(self.rect.x + dx, self.rect.y, 30, 30):
            dx = 0
        
        
        # Check collisions in y direction
        if stage.s_rect.colliderect(self.rect.x, self.rect.y + dy, 30, 30):
            if self.vel_y < 0:
                dy =  stage.s_rect.bottom - self.rect.top
                self.vel_y = 0
            elif self.vel_y > 0:
                dy = stage.s_rect.top - self.rect.bottom                        
        
        
                
        # Update the positionse
        self.rect.x += dx
        self.rect.y += dy
        
        if self.rect.bottom > 590:
            self.rect.bottom = 590
            dy = 0
            
        
        pygame.time.Clock().tick(60)
                
            
    def draw_player(self):
        ''' Draw the player on the screen'''
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (245,245,245), self.rect)
```

Stage--Pg 03

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
from random import randint

class Stage(Sprite):
    """Initialize the platform for player to jump on"""
    
    def __init__(self, screen):
        super(Stage, self).__init__()
        
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        
        self.s_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 540, 80, 10)
        self.s_rect.x = randint(10, 590)
                
    def draw_stage(self):
        ''' Draw the platform for the player'''
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (0,0,0), self.s_rect)
```

Game functions--Pg 04

```
import pygame


def responses(screen, player, event):
    ''' Check for responses'''
    
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            player.moving_up = True
            
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            player.moving_left = True
                
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            player.moving_right = True
                
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            player.moving_left = False
                
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            player.moving_right = False
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see about your code, you use `colliderect` with a collision box of 30x30: `colliderect(self.rect.x + dx, self.rect.y, 30, 30)`

Your level, or stage is 80x10: `pygame.Rect(0, 540, 80, 10)`

This means that the collision detection will only happen in a certain part of your stage. Here is a visual to help you better understand:
[image: visualization aid]

I believe this may be the source of your problems. After colliding with the red box, you have them teleport to around halfway, a time when they are still colliding with the box. This makes them constantly teleport back to where they were, as they are always getting put back into the red box, as they are colliding with it. This may cause some of your other errors.